# How to Process List of XML Files in a Directory then Add to Tables?

Tags: r, xml, loops, for-loop

I have the following code, which takes a local .xml file, parses it out into several tables.

First, I read the XML file in and establish the namespace information, along with the path to the part of the XML I want to output to tables.

```r
doc <- read_xml("XMLFILE01.xml") #read xml file in current directory
xml_ns(doc) #get namespace
xpath <- "//d1:REPORT" #main "root" table of the XML 
xpath_person <- "//d1:REPORT/d1:People/d1:ACRSPERSON" #inside the REPORT table, the table for People (multiple per REPORT)
```

I first make a table called report.

```
# REPORT TABLE
ns <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath, xml_ns(doc))    
items <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath, xml_ns(doc))    

# extract all children's names and values    
nodenames <-xml_name(xml_children(items))    
contents <-trimws(xml_text(xml_children(items)))    

# Need to create an index to associate the nodes/contents with each item    
itemindex<-rep(1:length(items), times=sapply(items, function(x) {length(xml_children(x))}))    

# store all information in data frame.    
crash1 <- data.frame(itemindex, nodenames, contents)    
crash <- pivot_wider(crash1, id_cols= itemindex, names_from = nodenames,
                     values_from = contents) # %>% unnest(cols = c(A, B, C, D))
```

I then run a very similar process on a subnode of the XML in and populate a table called "person" (as in all the people involved in a given report, a M:1 relationship).

```r
# PEOPLE TABLE
ns <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath_person, xml_ns(doc))
items <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath_person, xml_ns(doc))
nodenames <- xml_name(xml_children(items))
contents <- trimws(xml_text(xml_children(items)))
itemindex <- rep(1:length(items), times=sapply(items, function(x) {length(xml_children(x))}))
person1 <- data.frame(itemindex, nodenames, contents)

#Convert from long to wide format
person <- pivot_wider(person1, id_cols= itemindex, names_from = nodenames,
                      values_from = contents)  # %>% unnest(cols = c(A, B, C, D))
```

**My question** (and this should not be specific to XML parsing I would think):
How can I take a directory of XML files (I was able to make a list of the files in the local directory with the following command):

```r
inpt <- list.files("U:/tmp", pattern = "[.]xml")
j <- length(inpt)
```

And for **EACH XML FILE IN THE DIRECTORY**

1. Process it through the steps I have pasted above in some kind of loop which takes in mind the number of XML files in the directory, and is able to iterate thru them.
2. Append the each iteration's output to the previous iteration's output (so with each iteration, the `REPORT` and `PERSON` tables grow).
3. Move to the next item in the directory when the iteration completes.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for the amount of XML in the directory.

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

Simply generalize your process on one XML file in a user defined method.

```
build_dfs <- function(xml_file) {
   # PARSE DOC AND ASSIGN XPATHs
   doc <- read_xml(xml_file)
   ...

   # REPORT TABLE
   ...

   # PEOPLE TABLE
   ...

   # RETURN A NAMED LIST OF DATA FRAMES
   list(crash = crash, person = person)
}
```

Then build a list of objects with `lapply` that run through list of XML files iteratively calling method.

```r
# RETRIEVE XML FILES
xml_files <- list.files(file.path("U:", "tmp"), pattern = "[.]xml")

# PASS EACH XML FILE INTO METHOD
data_list <- lapply(xml_files, build_dfs)
```

Finally, run concatenation operations to stack all underlying data frame elements from list. Equivalent calls in `base` and `dplyr` are shown below:

```r
# RBIND ALL crash DATA FRAME ELEMENTS
crash_master_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(data_list, "[[", "crash"))
# crash_master_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(data_list, "[[", "crash"))

# RBIND ALL people DATA FRAME ELEMENTS
people_master_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(data_list, "[[", "people"))
# people_master_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(data_list, "[[", "people"))

rm(data_list)  # REMOVE ORIGINAL LARGE OBJECT
```